# how to query from multiple tables and get the column value from the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem: I need to get the username based on UnitNo on unitlog_table.

This is my query:

```
select distinct(avh.UnitNo), 
    isnull((select count(UnitNo) from unitlog_table 
            where UnitNo = avh.UnitNo 
              and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00' 
              and speed >= 41),0) as overord,
    isnull((select count(UnitNo) from unitlog_table 
            where UnitNo = avh.UnitNo 
              and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00' 
              and speed >= 71),0) as overex ,
    isnull((select count(UnitNo) from unitlog_table 
            where UnitNo = avh.UnitNo 
              and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00' 
              and speed >= 91),0) as overc,
    isnull((select count(UnitNo) from unitlog_table 
            where UnitNo = avh.UnitNo 
              and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00' 
              and speed >= 41 and speed >= 71 and speed >= 91), 0) as ttover,
    (select distinct(username) 
     from unit_table av 
     inner join users_table ut on ut.UnitNo = av.UnitNo 
     where UnitNo = avh.UnitNo) as username
from 
    unitlog_table avh 
where 
    avh.UnitNo in (select UnitNo from unit_table where userid = '1122')  
    and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00'
```

This is my table 1 (`unitlog_table`):

```
UnitNo        timestamp           speed
----------------------------------------
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:36:21.00    7.72
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:36:30.00    9.58
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:37:16.00    7.2
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:37:37.00    18.32
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:38:18.00    1.85
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:38:27.00    13.32
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:38:45.00    12.94
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:47:39.00    8.34
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:48:07.00    30.04
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:48:24.00    31.825
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:49:06.00    30.26
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:49:24.00    33.875
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:49:33.00    33.54
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:50:21.00    37.235
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:50:43.00    15.22
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:50:51.00    13.435
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:51:24.00    17.03
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:52:17.00    16.915
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:52:33.00    18.435
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:52:54.00    16.805
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:53:15.00    76.225
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:53:29.00    24.375
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:54:21.00    29.925
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:55:14.00    17.39
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:55:29.00    22.975
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:56:19.00    8.015
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:56:28.00    42.68
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:56:57.00    24.33
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:57:16.00    33.575
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:57:25.00    13.215
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:57:39.00    31.245
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:58:16.00    90.705
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:58:31.00    58.665
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:58:47.00    44.06
 unit1   2021-09-01 07:59:16.00    40.32
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:57:25.00    13.215
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:57:39.00    31.245
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:58:16.00    60.705
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:58:31.00    58.665
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:58:47.00    44.06
 unit2   2021-09-01 07:59:16.00    40.32
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:57:25.00    43.215
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:57:39.00    71.245
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:58:16.00    60.705
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:58:31.00    98.665
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:58:47.00    44.06
 unit3   2021-09-01 07:59:16.00    40.32
```

This is my table 2 (`unit_table`):

```
 UnitNo  userid
 --------------
 unit1   1122
 unit2   1122
 unit3   1122
 unit4   5577
 unit5   5577
 unit6   8888
```

And this is my table 3 (`users_table`):

```
 userid   username
--------------------
 1122     Rolly
 1122     Efren
 1122     Mark   --  edited to match OP comment
 5577     Bert
 5577     Jay
 8888     Eric
```

```
 expected results:

 username userid UnitNo  overord   overex   overc  ttover
 Rolly    1122   Unit1     2          1       2      5
 Efren    1122   Unit2     1          1       1      3
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ and belongs to `SELECT DISTINCT`. Simply skip the extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct avh.UnitNo, ...` to make code clearer (for everybody...)

Comment: is it correct that userid 1122 is used twice  (Rolly/Efren)?

Comment: @GrahamH yes it is correct, Rolly and Efren have the same userid but different UnitNo used

Comment: I cannot see how you can determine that Rolly equates to unit1....do you have another table that you are not mentioning?                  

 

why dont you want unit 3 results, that is also associated to userid 1122?

Comment: these are the 3 tables I think I need to join,
yes I need also unit 3 results

Comment: you need a table that has unitno/userid AND username....without that ytou cannot match as you want.   PS what is the username for unit3?

Comment: the username for unit3 is mark

Comment: have edited your original post accordingly.  Are you all good to go now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Please try this code and see if it works for you.
-- It doesnt match the result set you posted, but I beleive it is correct based on your sample data

SELECT
-- without a table that we can use to xref unitno to username we are forced to use CASE
-- this is not recommended and you should consider creating the necessary xref table
  CASE WHEN avh.UnitNo = 'unit1' THEN 'Rolly' 
       WHEN avh.UnitNo = 'unit2' THEN 'Efren' 
       WHEN avh.UnitNo = 'unit3' THEN 'Mark' END AS Username,
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  av.userid,
  avh.UnitNo,

-- I consider that you need to reference upper limits to give you the requisite breaks -- as below
  SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 41 AND speed < 71 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS overord,
  SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 71 AND speed < 91 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS overex,
  SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 91 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS overc,
  SUM(CASE WHEN speed >= 41 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ttover
FROM 
    unitlog_table AS avh
INNER JOIN 
    unit_table AS av ON avh.UnitNo = av.UnitNo
WHERE 
--  removed BETWWEEN and addeed half open intervals....google is your friend
    avh.timestamp >= '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' AND avh.timestamp < '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00'
    AND av.userid = 1122
GROUP BY
    avh.UnitNo,
    av.userid
```

| Username | userid | UnitNo | overord | overex | overc | ttover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rolly | 1122 | unit1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 5 |
| Efren | 1122 | unit2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| Mark | 1122 | unit3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: Glad it helped, look forward to seeing your idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really want conditional aggregation. You just need to join some tables, group, then conditionally aggregate them

> The condition `speed >= 41 and speed >= 71 and speed >= 91` seems logically incorrect.
> And the condition `between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00'` also seems wrong.
> Always use `half open intervals` >= AND <`rather than`BETWEEN`

```sql
select avh.UnitNo, 
    count(case when speed >= 41 then 1 end) as overord,
    count(case when speed >= 71 then 1 end) as overex ,
    count(case when speed >= 91 then 1 end) as overc,
    count(case when speed >= 41 and speed >= 71 and speed >= 91 then 1 end) as ttover,
    ut.username
from 
    unitlog_table avh 
inner join
    unit_table unt on avh.UnitNo = unt.UnitNo
inner join
    users_table ut on ut.userid = unt.userid
where 
    ut.userid = '1122'
    and timestamp between '2021-09-01 00:00:00.00' and '2021-09-01 08:00:00.00'
group by
    avh.UnitNo;
```

Comment: my problem is i dont have UnitNo column in users_table, only userid that I can connect these 3 tables

Comment: OK just need to rearrange the joins